# Fazer post com jquery

Tags: javascript, html, python, ajax, flask

Meu endpoint no python está funcionando perfeitamente, ja efetuei testes utilizando o postman.

O problema está na hora que o JavaScript vai chamar o método

Segue meu código JavaScript:

```
$("#Submit").click(function() {
    var info = $('#form-contact').serializeArray()

    var url = "http://0.0.0.0:5000/sendEmail";

      $.post(url,
      {
        name:  info[0].value,
        subject: info[1].value,
        email:  info[2].value,
        text: info[3].value
      });
});
```

Quando executo, aparece o seguinte erro:

> POST http://0.0.0.0:5000/sendEmail net::ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

Repito que pelo postman funciona perfeitamente com exatamente este endereço

Comment: Então a diferença entre o postman e o js é que o pedido está a ser feito pelo browser. Chrome? Experimenta com outro para despistar, e verifica se na aba "Network" das developer tools não está a acontecer nenhum redirecionamento pelo IP ou algo semelhante.

Comment: `http://0.0.0.0:5000`? esse endereço é inválido

Comment: é valido sim...

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e incluir a rota que responde a essa chamada?

Answer (score 1):

**127.0.0.1** é o endereço de loopback (também conhecido como localhost).

**0.0.0.0** é um meta-endereço não roteável usado para designar um endereço inválido. desconhecido, ou destino não aplicável (um espaço reservado 'sem endereço específico').

Com base nessas informações realizei alguns testes Locais no meu Django, sei que está usando o Flask mais a camada TCP/IP é a mesma.

Rodei meu servidor de teste local na porta 8000:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Tentei acesso pelo IP 0.0.0.0 e recebi o mesmo erro que você reportou:

```
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID
```

Pelo IP 127.0.0.1 tudo rodou conforme esperado

Tente pelo IP 127.0.0.1